# Why would I want to use Oracle for the Core DBs?

Tags: oracle

For a long time, Sitecore has included support for using Oracle for the Core DB and to be honest I pretty much ignored it and just assumed that Sitecore supports Oracle simply for cross-platform compatibility. I am no longer satisfied with my unfounded answer, since I cannot find any corroborating (or dissenting) information online, and would like to find out if anyone actually knows of a reason why I would want to use Oracle for the Core DBs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up until Sitecore 7.2, it was possible to use Oracle instead of SQL Server as a fully supported and alternative database.

You can find more details in the [Sitecore Compatibility Matrix](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164). The databases were included as part of the regular zip of the webroot which could be download from https://sdn.sitecore.net/default.aspx.

Oracle is not supported in Sitecore 8.0 or 8.1, but it is supported again in 8.2 when run in CMS only mode. In this case, Core Databases (master, web, core) are available as a separate download.

> If you intend to use Oracle for the Core db, please download the following file and check the installation guide for instructions on how to install and configure Oracle.

My guess if your confusion is around the wording on the download page, between  Sitecore.Core database and "Core databases required to run Sitecore".

Additionally, if you check a default installation of Sitecore 8.2 and `\App_Config\ConnectionStringsOracle.config` file then you will find `core`, `master` and `web` connectionstrings specified.

If your question is "Why would anyone want to use Oracle instead of SQL Server" in general, then this is the wrong place and would be entirely opinion based.

Comment: I see where I was unclear now, and it was on the wording of "core databases". I didn't understand why one would use SQL for one thing and Oracle for another. Thanks for clearing that up!